# What is the release date for Spring cloud version 2021.0.x?

Tags: spring-cloud, release, spring-cloud-vault-config

We are waiting for the latest release of  Spring cloud for a bugfix. What is the date for its release?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find all Spring Cloud releases with their dates https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/milestones . Here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/milestone/109 you can find the 2021.0.0 release. It is currently scheduled for 30.11.2021

Comment: Is it possible to release Spring Cloud 2021 (compatible to Spring Boot 2.6) already this week ? We plan to adopt to Spring Boot 2.6 still this year and are kinda blocked because of the missing Spring Cloud Release. Current Spring Cloud libraries seem to be incompatible with Spring Boot 2.6 .

Comment: You can use the latest RC (2021.0.0-RC1) from https://repo.spring.io/milestone see: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/